# linq query to fetch data by employee wise

Tags: linq

emp_master:

**empid,empname**

I am having one table called as

**employee_travel**

```
travelid       empid         location     date

1               101             abc        3/4/2014

2               102             lmn        4/4/2014

3               101             abc        5/4/2014

4               102             lmn        6/4/2014

5               101             xyz        7/4/2014

6               102             cdf        8/4/2014
```

now iIwant to display records employee wise like:

```
empid       location      date

101          abc           --

101          abc            --

101          xyz        

102          lmn

102          lmn

102          cdf
```

I have written following query in linq:

```
 var data = (from r in context.employee_travel

                        group r by new
                        {
                            r.Emp_id
                        } into g
                        select new
                        {
                            name = r.emp_master.empname,
                              r.date,
                            r.location

                        })
```

But it is giving me error on this line:

```
                     ****name = r.emp_master.empname,
                              r.date
                            r.location****
```

Here{name is used as anonomous type in query are name of d**atatextfield of my gridview**.}

Can anyone edit my linq query to suit my needs ????

Please please please help me. I am very much new to linq so I don't know how to write this query.

Answer (score 0):

```
from et in employee_travel
orderby et.empid
select new 
{ 
Employee = et.Employee,
TravelRecord = et, //if you want objects
Name = et.Employee.Name,
Date = et.Date //if you want simple types
}
```

In that sample I chose to return the entity, but you can of course return names, dates, etc. And you can add more ordering if you need.

Or you can just get the `employee_travel` entity and include the `employee` (make sure you have the right include property name)

```
db.employee_travel.Include("employee").OrderBy(et=>et.empid).ToList()
```